# Отправить данные в БД

Tags: php, yii, форма

Есть форма в представлении.
Подскажите, как отправить данные в БД или скиньте ссылку на статью, где это понятно расписывается.

Answer (score 2):

Вот [тут про ActiveRecord](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr) рассказывают, а вот [тут про создание форм](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.model)

Comment: Читал. Не совсем понятно.

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны понимать, что есть **форма**, а есть **модель** (к примеру, форма регистрации и модель пользователя). Изначально заполняется форма, после отправки форма с данными валидируется. Если валидация успешна, то создается и наполняется модель данными из формы. Затем уже модель валидируется и, если все ок, то сохраняется.

Вот пример кода из контроллера, который обрабатывает POST запрос:

```
$register = new RegisterForm();
$result = null;

if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest){
    $post = Yii::app()->request->getPost(RegisterForm::FORM_NAME);
    $register->email = $post['email'];
    $register->password = $post['password'];
    if($register->validate()){
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $register->email;
        $user->password = $register->password;
        $user->status = USER::STATUS_WAIT_CONFIRM;
        if($user->validate()){
            $user->save();      
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl("user/login"));
        }
        else{
            $result['errors'] = $user->getErrors();
        }
    }
    else{
        $result['errors'] = $register->getErrors(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Если не сложно, опишите весь процесс передачи данных из формы в БД.

Comment: прочитайте еще раз первый абзац. Это и есть процесс передачи данных от формы до сохранения их в БД.